# y=\sin (\frac{1}{x}) : Connected subspaces and homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, connectedness

Given:

$S_{1} = \{ (x,y): y=\sin (\frac{1}{x}), 0<x \le 1 \}$

$S_{2} = \{ (x,y): y=\sin (\frac{1}{x}), -1\le x <0  \}$

Let $S= S_{1} \cup S_{2} \cup \{(0,0)\}$

1) Is S connected as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the Euclidean topology?

2) Let $T=S_{1} \cup S_{2} \cup \{ (0,y): -1 \le y \le 1\}$.  Are $S$ and $T$ homeomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is connected, but it's not path-connected. Look up "topologist's sine curve". (This isn't the topologist's sine curve, but it's closely related.)

To show $S$ is connected, we use the theorems that the closure of a connected set is connected, and that the union of two connected sets with a nonempty intersection is connected. (Neither of these theorems are hard to prove.) The closure of $S_1$ *in the space $S$* is $S_1\cup\{(0,0)\}$, and likewise for the closure of $S_2$; then the union of these two closures is connected since their intersection is $\{(0,0)\}$.

(2) is also closely related to the topologist's sine curve. $T$ is not homeomorphic to $S$. Reason: $S$ has two path-components homeomorphic to the unit interval, and $T$ has three.

Comment: thank you:) 
But could you tell me more ad1? How to show that it is connected?